# Can not create tuning_model Google Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have tried multiple times to create a tuning_model, but unfortunately, I always got this bug. I have checked very carefully the jsonl file and find no problem there. Please someone give me an idea about this.

I am expecting that this model tuned successfully

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM6zP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyWEE.png